# JQuery multiple select filter bug

Tags: multipleselection

I have a multiple select with a filter. Filtering works properly, but when you select a filtered item it does not change to the selected state (there is no tick in the box of the selected item).

I followed the instructions of the offical JQuery Mobile page. The only difference is that they do not use a multiple select. Is there a workaround to have the filter functionality with multiple select boxes?

[JQuery Mobile filterable select](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/#&ui-state=dialog)

My select:

```
<form>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="title-filter-menu">Placeholder:</label>
    <select id="title-filter-menu" multi data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select">
        <option>Select fruit...</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="peach">Peach</option>
        <option value="lemon">Lemon</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

JS

```
  ( function( $ ) {
function pageIsSelectmenuDialog( page ) {
    var isDialog = false,
        id = page && page.attr( "id" );
    $( ".filterable-select" ).each( function() {
        if ( $( this ).attr( "id" ) + "-dialog" === id ) {
            isDialog = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return isDialog;
}
$.mobile.document
    // Upon creation of the select menu, we want to make use of the fact that the ID of the
    // listview it generates starts with the ID of the select menu itself, plus the suffix "-menu".
    // We retrieve the listview and insert a search input before it.
    .on( "selectmenucreate", ".filterable-select", function( event ) {
        var input,
            selectmenu = $( event.target ),
            list = $( "#" + selectmenu.attr( "id" ) + "-menu" ),
            form = list.jqmData( "filter-form" );
        // We store the generated form in a variable attached to the popup so we avoid creating a
        // second form/input field when the listview is destroyed/rebuilt during a refresh.
        if ( !form ) {
            input = $( "<input data-type='search'></input>" );
            form = $( "<form></form>" ).append( input );
            input.textinput();
            list
                .before( form )
                .jqmData( "filter-form", form ) ;
            form.jqmData( "listview", list );
        }
        // Instantiate a filterable widget on the newly created selectmenu widget and indicate that
        // the generated input form element is to be used for the filtering.
        selectmenu
            .filterable({
                input: input,
                children: "> option[value]"
            })
            // Rebuild the custom select menu's list items to reflect the results of the filtering
            // done on the select menu.
            .on( "filterablefilter", function() {
                selectmenu.selectmenu( "refresh" );
            });
    })
    // The custom select list may show up as either a popup or a dialog, depending on how much
    // vertical room there is on the screen. If it shows up as a dialog, then the form containing
    // the filter input field must be transferred to the dialog so that the user can continue to
    // use it for filtering list items.
    .on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, data ) {
        var listview, form;
        // We only handle the appearance of a dialog generated by a filterable selectmenu
        if ( !pageIsSelectmenuDialog( data.toPage ) ) {
            return;
        }
        listview = data.toPage.find( "ul" );
        form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
        // Attach a reference to the listview as a data item to the dialog, because during the
        // pagecontainerhide handler below the selectmenu widget will already have returned the
        // listview to the popup, so we won't be able to find it inside the dialog with a selector.
        data.toPage.jqmData( "listview", listview );
        // Place the form before the listview in the dialog.
        listview.before( form );
    })
    // After the dialog is closed, the form containing the filter input is returned to the popup.
    .on( "pagecontainerhide", function( event, data ) {
        var listview, form;
        // We only handle the disappearance of a dialog generated by a filterable selectmenu
        if ( !pageIsSelectmenuDialog( data.prevPage ) ) {
            return;
        }
        listview = data.prevPage.jqmData( "listview" ),
        form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
        // Put the form back in the popup. It goes ahead of the listview.
        listview.before( form );
    });
})( jQuery );
```

CSS

```
.ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-input-search {
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-content {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-selectmenu-list {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-selectmenu-list li.ui-first-child .ui-btn {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-header {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Same problem in my application. No solutions yet??

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the right option is selected, but the shown selected state in the filtered list is wrong. 
If you have the options

```
a1
b1
c2
d2
```

with an filter "1" you get

```
a1
b1
```

you can correctly select each of them. 
If you filter "2"
you get

```
c2
d2
```

if you select c2 (which is the first option of the selected list and the third of the original list) jquerymobile tries to show selected state on the !third! option of the !filtered list". thats the bug.

However, with the basic filtered select example ist works (first one in http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/)
Problem here: The filter bar (search input) is above the select Header (Closing icon + Label).